# DynamoDB: Making range query v/s query each item separately

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Lets say, I have several items in the dynamodb with the same partition-key and different sort-keys.

Is there any difference between consumed read capacity units if I query the records using a sort-key constraint in a single go v/s query each item individually? Assume that the number of sort-keys to be fetched at-a-time are around 50. The [official-documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html) says that

> One read capacity unit represents one strongly consistent read per
>   second, or two eventually consistent reads per second, for an item up
>   to 4 KB in size.

From this definition, it doesn't seem that there should be a difference since this definition is independent of how we query the database.

Apart from additional network delay, does the second approach have any other downside?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the costing is based on Read Capacity Units (RCU) and Write Capacity Units (WCU).

**RCU formula:-**

```
RCU = read capacity unit per item × number of reads per second
```

Before going into the below calculation, calculate the item size. You can get the item size from AWS console.

Go to the dynamodb table on AWS console --> Overview tab --> See at the bottom.

[image]

Lets talk about RCU. In the above case,

**Scenario 1 - Getting all the data in one go using hash key only:-**

In this scenario, the number of items read will be high (i.e. 50 items data). Calculate the size and check how many RCU required.

**Scenario 2 - Getting the data multiple times using hash key and sort key:-**

In this scenario, the API will be called multiple times. So, the number of reads per second will go up. Calculate the number of reads required and check how many RCU required.

Compare the RCU calculated in scenario 1 and 2. Choose the option which has less RCU in order to save cost.